# Extracting links and saving positions in HTML

Tags: php, html, regex, data-structures, domdocument

I have html and what I'd like to accomplish is the following:

- Scan the text for `anchor` links.
- Extract the `anchor link` details and place a marker to its location in the `html`
- Upon saving the text in the database, replace the markers back with the `anchor link` associated to its position.

So, here's the starting html:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <a href="somelink">Some text</a>
            <p>Some paragraph text</p>
            <a href="someotherlink">Some other text</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the resulting html after replacement:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            {articleLink0}
            <p>Some paragraph text</p>
            {articleLink1}
        </body>
    </html>
```

Then, in the data structure it would be built as. As you can see, the index positions are reflected (for example `{articleLink0}` would corrolate to `$data[0]`.

```
    $data = array(
        0 => array('href'=>'somelink','text'=>'Some text'),
        1 => array('href'=>'someotherlink','text'=>'Some other text')
    );
```

**Finally, I need a method of placing back the contents in there designated position in the data structure.**

Comment: As important as telling us what you want to achieve is, showing us what you have tried to accomplish this is even more important. Then, you ask a question regarding a particular aspect of your code.

Comment: @Dagon I'll make a pseudo approach to my thoughts. I haven't written any actual code yet.

Comment: then please read about asking questions on S.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the `$data` array, generate a string with the rendered `a` tag inside, use the index to generate the replacement string and finally replace the replacement string with the generated `a` tag.

- `a` tag rendering => regular string concatenation
- generation of the replacement => regular string concatenation
- the replacement itself => `str_replace`

Something like this should work:

```php
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    // value and href have to be escaped, if they contain unsafe characters
    $aTag = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $value['href'], $value['text']);
    $toReplace = sprintf('{articleLink%d}', $key);

    $htmlContent = str_replace($toReplace, $aTag, $htmlContent);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code I can look at? I'm a hands on person so I need to see what is occurring so I can understand your idea.

Comment: I'm making pseudo code as to what I believe should occur. Ill update in a moment.